# Individual axes titles in a facet plot?

Tags: plotly-python

I have a Pandas dataframe that I would like to plot with different labels on each yaxis using plotly.
For example

```
fig = dataframe.plot(
    x="t", y="value",
    facet_col="variable_label",
    facet_col_wrap=2,
    yaxes_titles="multiplier_label",  # This is unfortunately not a valid keyword argument
).update_yaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True)
```

Is there a way to update each yaxis with a different title?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - it is quite complicated due to the ordering of yaxes being from bottom to top, left to right! I needed the following utility function:

```
def get_yaxis(fig, i, facet_col_wrap):
    """Get the yaxis for the ith facet in a facet plot"""
    yaxes = list(fig.select_yaxes())
    n = len(yaxes)
    n_cols = min(facet_col_wrap, n)
    n_rows = n // n_cols
    idx = [[n-((1+r)*n_cols-c) for c in range(n_cols)] for r in range(n_rows)]
    idx = [item for sublist in idx for item in sublist]
    return yaxes[idx[i]]
```

With this function and a list of my desired yaxes_titles at hand, I can finally do:

```
for i, yaxis_title in enumerate(yaxis_titles):
    get_yaxis(fig, i, facet_col_wrap).update(title_text=yaxis_title)
```